# Does settings in Vim's configuration file '_vimrc ' follow an order according to the document's flow (top to bottom)?

Tags: vim, configuration

Its a bit weird, I wanted to deactivate automatic backups in gVIM when saving, so I placed `set nobackup` in the top of the file _vimrc and it didn't work. Then I placed that line below the following lines:

```
set nocompatible
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin
```

and it worked.

basically `set nobackup` doesn't works like this:

```
set nobackup

 set nocompatible
    source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
    source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
    behave mswin
```

and but works like this:

```
 set nocompatible
    source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
    source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
    behave mswin

set nobackup
```

Is this normal? Do VIM settings interfere with other settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
```

means that vim runs the configuration in those files before loading the lines after. As ["just somebody" said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033546/does-settings-in-vims-configuration-file-vimrc-follow-an-order-according-to/2033558#2033558), in vimrc_example.vim, the backup is activated, so, in your first example, your first set the nobackup and then it's unactivated by the .vim file.

Answer (score 2):

vimrc_example.vim contains:

```
if has("vms")
  set nobackup      " do not keep a backup file, use versions instead
else
  set backup        " keep a backup file
endif
```

you could have easily checked this yourself, you know. ;)

**edit**

oh, and I'd suggest getting rid of the includes and the `behave mswin` directive.  it makes vim turns vim into a different text editor.  one of vim's great strengths is that it works the same everywhere: MS Windows, X Windows, unix terminal... mswin voids this feature.

if you get used to `^S` for `:w` and `^Q` for `^V`, you'll weep when you try to use vim in a unix terminal (they mean something to the terminal, and vim won't see the keystrokes at all); *backspace* is also troublesome (`^H` on most systems, `^?` on GNU/Linux, different terminals have different defaults), ditto for *delete* and *alt*.  etc.

Comment: What does the ```has('vms')``` command means? VMS as in the operating system?